# Cannot use arrow keys in npm command line

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

I'm trying to setup FireBase functions, and when I use the command

```
npm firebase init functions
```

I am asked to choose a default project for the directory I've set up. My list is populated correctly, but I'm not able to select the options using the arrow keys. (nothing happens when I press up or down, and even enter)

Here are my versions:

1. Windows 10
2. NODEJS v8.1.0
3. npm v5.0.3
4. FireBase v3.9.1

A screenshot of the problem:

[image: cannot select the options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all you had to do was update your Firebase CLI tools, and downgrade the npm version.

I solved the issue by downgrading my NodeJS to v6.11.0.

Also, I updated my FireBase CLI by running

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Use nvm-windows as a version controller for your npm.

Should do the trick.

Link: [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)